# How to tell which attribute Weka's OneR classifier uses for provided dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka

I'm currently using Weka's OneR classifier and below is the generated output. **Is there any way to tell which attribute the OneR classifier is using for the dataset I have loaded?**

[image]

Comment: You could also try the OneR package from CRAN: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=OneR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's variable 0.670968.
Which likely indicates that the file you loaded doesn't have the names you intended.

I've highlighted where OneR shows the variable it uses below (using the iris.arff file).
[image]